# Change color of selected MatCheckbox

Tags: css, angular-material

I need to change the color of one Material checkbox when it is selected.

I need to invert the colors, so I already changed the frame:

```
mat-checkbox.inverted-checkbox .mat-checkbox-frame {
   border-color: white!important;
}
```

But now I need to make the background of the selected checkbox white and the mark inside blue.

I try with:

```
 mat-checkbox.inverted-checkbox .mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-
    background {
      background-color: white!important;
    }
```

But it's not work

this is the checkbox

```
 <mat-checkbox class="inverted-checkbox"></mat-checkbox>
```

and here you can find the example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-focghc

Comment: Can you provide a a Minimal, Reproducible Example --> https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-focghc
change the color of the first selected checkbox

Answer (score 0):

If you'll go inside the .mat-checkbox-background you'll see that the check icon is a path element and it's color is set by stroke: #fafafa!important; css property.

Comment: so what I have to do?

Comment: Override this style
stroke: #fafafa!important;

Comment: I don't see any stroke, I am using material 7, can you give me the code to do it, I need to override just 1 checkbox